# jQuery datepicker Change Year Dropdown Not Display

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an issue about jQuery Datepicker. Change Year/Month dropdowns not displaying.

My code:

```
$( document ).ready((function () {
    $("#dtBirthday").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
      });
}));
```

and

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.creditApply.User.Birthday, new { @class = "txt-form", @id = "dtBirthday", @required = true, placeholder = "Doğum tarihi GG/AA/YYYY"})
```

Comment: I dont have enough point for post images so i just write it.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/hocsa3e1/1/

Comment: Yes, but i dont see these on my machine in development.

Comment: You're using the jQuery UI Datepicker, not some third-party datepicker, right?

Comment: Could you have multiple calls to `$("#dtBirthday").datepicker()`? Only the first one sets the options.

Comment: No just one datepicker is in there..

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question to figure out what you're doing differently on your site from what you've posted. Can you provide a link to the live site?